# How set OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership property of sitegroup using JSOM?

Tags: jsom, groups, update

I'm trying to set the OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership property of all the sitegroup s on my site collection to FALSE programmatically. I can get the values with code below, but I'm not quite connecting the dots on how to set the values of the existing groups. How do I update that property? I understand the sitegroup collection has a property of set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership but I don't know how to use it.

```
//global variables
var showHtml = ''; 
// define a ClientContext for the specified SP site    
 var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

// attach a onRequestFailed function to the client context.
ctx.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
});

function doWork() {
    //debugger;
    var groupCollection = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    ctx.load(groupCollection);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var groupEnumerator = groupCollection.getEnumerator();
        var groupCount = 0;
        while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var ogroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
            var currGroup = ogroup.get_objectData().get_properties();
            console.log("Title:",currGroup.Title,"ID",currGroup.Id,"OnlyAllMembersViewMembership",currGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership);
            groupCount ++;
            showHtml += currGroup.Title + "; " + currGroup.Id +"; " + currGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership + "<br>";
        }
        $('#show').append("<b>Number of groups: " + groupCount + "</b><br><br>");
        $('#show').append(showHtml);
    });
};

window.onload = doWork;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
//global variables
var showHtml = ''; 
// define a ClientContext for the specified SP site    
 var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

// attach a onRequestFailed function to the client context.
ctx.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
});

function doWork() {
    //debugger;
    var groupCollection = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    ctx.load(groupCollection);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var groupEnumerator = groupCollection.getEnumerator();
        var groupCount = 0;
        while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var ogroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();     

            var currGroup = ogroup.get_objectData().get_properties();
            console.log("Title:",currGroup.Title,"ID",currGroup.Id,"OnlyAllMembersViewMembership",currGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership);
            groupCount ++;
            showHtml += currGroup.Title + "; " + currGroup.Id +"; " + currGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership + "<br>";

            //change OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership property
            ogroup.set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership(false);
            ogroup.update();
            ctx.load(ogroup);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        }
        $('#show').append("<b>Number of groups: " + groupCount + "</b><br><br>");
        $('#show').append(showHtml);
    });
};

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    console.log("success");
}
function onQueryFailed(){
    console.log("error");
}

window.onload = doWork;
```

Comment: Glad to hear that ! Could you please mark it as answer ?